# How to POST a product on WooCommerce with a custom Category

Tags: php, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I am trying to import a lot of products from a database to WooCommerce via API. These products belong to different categories. 
What I want to achieve is, when I use POST to push a product into WooCommerce, that it takes the category name assigned to the product and creates a category on WooCommerce, or if that category exists, skips creating a new category and assigns the product in that desired category (all by name, not ID).
I can't seem to find a proper solution and therefore am posting this question for the more experienced devs.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
data = [
['name' = 'test']
]
$woocommerce->post('products/batch', $data);
```

I know that if I replace the `'name' = 'test' with 'id' = category-id` it works, given that a category with that specified id exists, but that's not the point. Again, I am trying to push a product into an empty database and create that category using the name I'm giving, in our example that'd be `test`.